# Close JQuery plug in by clicking away

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I'm using a plug in called tooltipster, to activate it's simply:

```
$('#tooltip').tooltipster();
```

I want to close it by clicking away, anywhere else on the page, so am trying:

```
$(document).one("click", "body", function(){        
    $('#tooltip').tooltipster('hide');
});
```

But all this seems to do is cause me having to click twice to actually fire the tooltip and it doesn't hide when clicking away.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There's a typo. $(document).one should be $(document).on</strike>

```
$('body').click(function(){        
    $('body').tooltipster('hide');
});

$('#tooltip').click(function(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The hide code was taken from the tooltipster docs at http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#demos

Comment: Hi, It's not a typo .one is valid JQuery - anyway, this doesn't work either I'm afraid

Comment: First time i've come across it. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah that can't work because it's cancelling itself out, you're clicking within body to start and close it  - will try a fiddle

Comment: you have typo in first line )click( >> should be >> ).click( - but it works! thanks mate!

Comment: Fixed. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(body).click(function(e)
{
   $('#tooltip').slideUp('fast');
});
$('#tooltip').click(function(e)
{
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but get: ReferenceError: body is not defined